# Changing order of Newtonsoft.Json SerialiazeObject

Tags: c#, .net

I have two model classes that have been serialized as such:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {person = new[] {personList}, jobs = new[] {jobsList} });
```

personList is a list of type List and jobsList is  a list of type List.

Currently the output result is

```
{person: [{person1},{person2}]], jobs: [{job1},{job2}]
```

What I am tryint to get as an output:

```
{person: [{person1},{job1}]], [{person2},{job2}]
```

Basically I am trying to return the result of the two lists alternatively. I tried placing

```
[JsonProperty(order = #)]
```

and that made no difference. Please help.

Comment: The job of Newtonsoft is to serialize data not perform data joins and manipulation. You should be doing that ahead of passing the data into Newtonsoft. Are you familiar with Linq?

Comment: How is a person related to a job?   Is there some kind of property in them both that relates one to another?

Comment: @RexHenderson no I am not much familiar with linq. Please can you tell me how  I use it to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what I was doing wrong. I was missing the list of the second model class in the first model class.

```
public class person  //model 1
{
  public string name {get; set;}
  public int id {get; set;}

  public List<jobs> {get; set;} //THIS IS WHAT I WAS MISSING

}
```